# I need to return values from open window to user object without close current window

Tags: powerbuilder

I have user object hold datawindow , i need to open other window to search on it and make some operation then insert in datawindow on user object without close window.

Answer (score 0):

I think of two possibilities :

**Direct access (quick and dirty) :**

- You could open the second window with `OpenWithParm()` and give the datawindow as argument.
- In the `open()` event of that second window, you can get that datawindow via `Message.PowerobjectParm`
- insert what you need to in the given DW.

**Better way (decoupling the process and the GUI) :**

- add a dedicated method to the first window that accesses directly the DW
- use `OpenWithParm()` with `this` as argument to let the second window who is calling it
- get the caller with the `Message.PowerobjectParm`
- call the dedicated method of the caller to add data into the DW